# polynomials maximum value in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $P(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$ be a polynomial of degree $n$, $n \in \mathbb N$ and is even and $a_n < 0$

Prove that P reaches its maximum value in $\mathbb R$

Thoughts:

I've tried to do it in the same way as you do the proof with $a_n > 0$ but I cant get it right

Comment: Note when $a_n>0$ that $P$ might not reach its max, for there may not be one, consider $P(x)=1 \cdot x^2.$

Answer (score 2):

the limite of your polynom in $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ is $-\infty$, then you should be able to conclude using the fact that a continuous function reach his maximum on a segment.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $g(x) :=x^{-n}P(x)$. As $|x| \to \infty$, it's easy to see $g(x) \to a_n < 0$. But since $x^n \geq 0$, it follows that $P(x) = x^ng(x) \to -\infty$ as $|x| \to \infty$. When $|x|>M$, $f(x) < f(0)$ so it suffices to consider the max of $f$ on $[-M, M]$ which exists since the interval is compact.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since $n$ is even, it's first derivative must be a polynomial of odd degree, which always has atleast one real root.

Comment: Does the existence of that root *imply* that $P$ reaches its maximum in $\mathbb{R}$? [After all, at such a root of $P',$ it may be $P$ has neither a relative max nor a relative min...]